# Success handler not working after Symfony2 login

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-forms, symfony-2.6

The goal is to do something after authentication success in Symfony2.

In order to do that I have extended `AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface` creating a service for the form login in order to be its success handler.

Here is the firewall in the security.yml file (where the success handler is declared):

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            check_path: fos_user_security_check
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            success_handler: foo_user.component.authentication.handler.login_success_handler 
        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true
```

Here is the `LoginSuccessHandler` service (created in the UserBundle):

```
namespace Foo\UserBundle\Component\Authentication\Handler;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Router;

class LoginSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface
{

    protected $router;
    protected $security;

    public function __construct(Router $router, SecurityContext $security)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->security = $security;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
   {
        $referer_url = $request->headers->get('referer');                       
        $response = new RedirectResponse($referer_url);

        return $response;
    }
}
```

And here is the services.xml from the UserBundle:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 

<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     
xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services 
http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">
    <parameters>
        <parameter key="foo_user.component.authentication.handler.login_success_handler.class">
            Foo\UserBundle\Component\Authentication\Handler\LoginSuccessHandler
        </parameter>
    </parameters>
    <services>
        <service id="foo_user.component.authentication.handler.login_success_handler" 
        class="%foo_user.component.authentication.handler.login_success_handler.class%">
            <tag name="monolog.logger" channel="security"/>
            <argument type="service" id="router"/>
            <argument type="service" id="security.context"/>
            <argument type="service" id="service_container"/>
        </service>
    </services>
</container>
```

The `LoginSuccessHandler` constructor is being called and I'm getting no error messages.

The problem I'm having is that `onAuthenticationSuccess` isn't being called after login success. May be I'm missing something?

Comment: Well, I think everything looks just fine here except that service tag `monolog.logger`. Could that be the cause?

Comment: I've tried to remove that but the problem remains the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my working solutions I implements the method *onSecurityInteractiveLogin* in my listener as:

```
public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event) 
    {
        $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();
    }
```

Try implementing this method too.

I have your identical configuration (security.yml and service definition) but i don't use fosuserbunde.

hope this help