# how to make the onAuthenticationSuccess function being called

Tags: symfony, authentication

I would like to have some action after a success authentification.

I created a class extended DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler, and redefined the onAuthenticationSuccess function.

Though the authentication is a success, the programm never goes to the function : why ?

---

```
namespace my_name_space;

use   Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\HttpUtils;
use Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger;


class AuthenticationSuccessHandler extends DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
private $em;
private $logger;

function __construct(Logger $logger, HttpUtils $httpUtils, EntityManager $em) {
    parent::__construct($httpUtils);
    $this->em = $em;
    $this->logger = $logger;
}

public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token) {
    $this->logger->info("onAuthenticationSuccess");
    $response = parent::onAuthenticationSuccess($request, $token);
    $token->eraseCredentials();        
    $token->getUser()->addRole('ROLE_USER');

    return $response;
}
```

}

```
services:
security.authentication.success.handler:
    class: MY\NAMESPACE\AuthenticationSuccessHandler
    arguments: ["@monolog.logger.php","@security.http_utils", "@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager"]
```

security.yml

```
form_login:
            check_path: _security_check
            use_referer: true
            use_forward: true
            login_path: my_login
            success_handler: security.authentication.success.handler
```

Comment: Are you [define success hundler in the firewall](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15908856/do-something-just-after-symfony2-login-success-and-before-redirect)?

Maybe you can provide more detais about security configeration?

Comment: that must be that... right (though the constructor is called).. how do I do that ? I just added in the form_login of the security.yml the success_handler: security.authentication.success.handler  option

Comment: You should set here `success_handler: security.authentication.success.handler` your service name

Comment: Please add your service declaration + the firewall from security.yml

Comment: 've found any good answer ? i'm not ok with the answer .
It does not say why it does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can listen for the event that is triggered after a successful login attempt by registering a service to the related security tag:

```
app.login_listener:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\LoginListener
    arguments:
        - @security.authorization_checker
        - @security.token_storage
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.interactive_login, method: yourMethod }
```

Where **yourMethod** can contain the code you want to execute.

Comment: really... why can't i Use the default on success handler which should call the onAuthenticationSuccess method that I redefined ?

Comment: Think the success_listener notation is wrong, instead of `security.authentication.success.handler` you should call the service `"@security.authentication.success.handler"`.

Comment: you mean in the security.yml ? I say it again (the constructor of this class is called)

Comment: Think you are somehow trying to override / decorate the default service because the service keys are identical, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15918617/symfony2-extending-defaultauthenticationsuccesshandler and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27826964/success-handler-not-working-after-symfony2-login

Comment: I know this post and it is like mine.. but the method is not triggered

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of same issues on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15918617/symfony2-extending-defaultauthenticationsuccesshandler), [github](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5432), [google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/symfony2/PFPxF8buloU), most of them are unsolved.

Also, you should define a custom `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` rather than extending the default.

Example:

**services.yml**

```
login_success_handler:
    class:  YourBundle\EventListener\CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler
    arguments:  ["@doctrine", "@router"]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.interactive_login, method: onSecurityInteractiveLogin }
```

**CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler.php**

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Routing\RouterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    private $em;
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em, RouterInterface $router) 
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event) 
    {
        $this->onAuthenticationSuccess($event->getRequest(), $event->getAuthenticationToken());
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token) 
    {    
        $user = $token->getUser();
        $user->eraseCredentials();        
        $user->addRole('ROLE_USER');

        $this->em->flush() // If you don't do this, your changes will not be saved.
        $response = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('your_success_route'));

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Don't need of manually set the `success_handler` in your form, because the `SuccessHandler` is an `EventListener` and will be used on the corresponding event.

Comment: well it does not work either for me... onSecurityInteractiveLogin is not called... let's wait for some other people if it works for them

Comment: Very strange. Hope someone fix the problem. Don't forget to keep the code in your question same has your actual implementation.

Comment: If you can, remove your whole listener to restart from zero and try this one https://gist.github.com/marydn/8061424

Comment: works when i change to "@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager" in symfony 5

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the interactive login event is proposed here therefore I write a separate answer. @chalasr's answer worked for me but with security.authentication.success event:

```
login_success_handler:
    class:  YourBundle\EventListener\CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler
    arguments:  ["@doctrine", "@router"]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.authentication.success, method: onAuthenticationSuccess }
```